# Is O(K + (N-K)logK) equivalent to O(K + N log K)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Can we say `O(K + (N-K)logK)` is equivalent to `O(K + N logK)` for `1 < = K <= N`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **they are not equivalent** and it depends on the value of `k`. If `k` is equal to `N`, then the first complexity is `O(N)`, and the second complexity is `O(N + Nlog N)` which is equivalent to `O(NlogN)`. However, `O(N)` is not equivalent to `O(N log N)`.

Moreover, if a function is in `O(K + (N-K) log K)` is in `O(K + N log K)` (definitely for every positive `K`), and the proof of this is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So should we always specify a tighter asymptotic bound for the algorithm when possible?  As you mentioned, the algorithm is definitely in O(K + N log K), but a tighter range will be O(K + (N-K) log K).

Comment: @user1861872 Absolutely tighter bound give us more information about the complexity and we like it : )

Answer (score 1):

Yes because in the worst case `(N-K) logK` is at most `N logK` given your constraints since `1 <= K <= N`.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

If they are equivalent, then every function in O(k + (n-k)log k) is also in O(k + n log k) and vice-versa.

Let f(n,k) = n log k

This function is certainly in O(k + n log k), but *not* in O(k + (n-k)log k).

Let g(n,k) = k + (n-k)log k

Then as x approaches infinity, f(x,x)/g(x,x) grows without bound, since:

f(x,x) / g(x,x)

= (x log x) / x

= log x

See the definition of big-O notation for multiple variables: http://mathwiki.cs.ut.ee/asymptotics/04_multiple_variables

Wikipedia provides the same information, but in less accessible notation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables